# CocoaPod installed but doesn't see Swift code

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I've been struggling with integrating an [ImagePicker library](https://github.com/Athlee/ImagePickerKit) into my project. CocoaPods website shows [this pod](https://cocoapods.org/?q=ImagePickerkit) correctly except for the documentation even though it's documented, guess it simply doesn't see the code...

Steps to recreate my issue:

Install a pod through CocoaPods.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'TestProject' do
  use_frameworks!
pod 'ImagePickerKit', '~> 0.2'
end
```

Import `ImagePickerKit` module and try to implement some protocol...

[image]

What can be wrong?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. Xcode doesn't complain about not conforming to a protocol, it simply doesn't know anything about this protocol ("Use of undeclared type ...").

Comment: Is it not the errors for you to implement the protocol methods in your code?

Comment: Do a clean rebuild. It should work.

Comment: Thank you for replies. Unfortunately, it does not help. For some reason Xcode doesn't see the pod's source files.

Comment: Isn't that error is about not-implemented protocol methods. ??

Comment: No, it is not. It would say that your type does not conform to a protocol.

Comment: Okay guys, the problem is solved. Thank you for participating!

Comment: Do not add "solved" to your question. If an answer solved your issue, *mark the answer as accepted*, that's the official way of saying "solved". If not, you can always post an answer yourself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the library was updated and integration finally went well. The problem occurred because the previous versions of this library were using `internal` access modifiers which CocoaPods didn't see or just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the app, sometime after you install the pod you have to run it in order to make the compiler recognize the new pod.

Answer (score -1):

You did eveything correctly, Apple shows you that it's wrong because you didn't yet use Cropable, so once you will have write some code using it, the error will disappear :)